# How to count time in two different activities?

Tags: java, android

I don't know if this is even possible but I have several activities, two at the moment, and I have time limit of 20 minutes for player to finish the game. The problem is, he starts at one activity, then goes to another and so on. How to keep the timer going even in another activity, and keep it visible in a textView?

EDIT for minhaz:

```
public void getTime(long value, String PREFERENCE_NAME){
        SharedPreferences myPrefs = mContext.getSharedPreferences(PREFERENCE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEditor = myPrefs.edit();
        prefsEditor.putLong("time", value);
        prefsEditor.commit();
    }
```

Comment: Keep a static variable in a global timer class

Comment: Or create a Singleton with the gamestate in it.

Comment: ...or extend `Application`.

Comment: @Telthien How to do that? Can you give some example of that timer? Or some link. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Just create a global timer class.

```
class Timer {
    private static long startTime = -1;

    public static void reset() {Timer.startTime = -1;}
    public static void initialize() {Timer.startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();}
    public static long getTimeMillis() {return System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;}

    private Timer() {}
}
```

Then, by importing this class (wherever you've put it), you can access the current time.

Comment: Is it possible to do all of this with countdown timer?

Comment: Yes, see if you can figure it out. Hint: it's just subtraction.

Answer (score 0):

As stated by Lukas, extending Application would be nice.

You could also use a preference that store the time at which the timer was started...

But working working with timer start time sounds the best way, I think.

Comment: I need to extend Activity.

Comment: @marjanbaz You can extend the Application class, then get the application class from each activity to get your global state variables.

Answer (score 0):

Start timer from one activity and when user switch to next one pass the value inside an Intent

```
Intent intent=new Intent(Current.class, NextActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("time", timer_value);
```

And on the another activity get the value as

```
time_value=intent.getLongExtra("time")
```

In this way user will get some buffer time, when their is delay in between activities, as starting activity call is Asynchronous. You can call `finsh()` or do something else based on your requirement from the time.

Extending [Application](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html) class is also a good solution, if you want to limit time from starting the app. But thats not exactly the total play time.

**Update:**
For storing data, you can use persistence storage based on your requirement. Right now, [shared preference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) look like a good candidate.

Store Data

```
    SharedPreferences myPrefs = mContext.getSharedPreferences(PREFERENCE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEditor = myPrefs.edit();
    prefsEditor.putLong("time", value);
    prefsEditor.commit();
```

Retrieve data

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = mContext.getSharedPreferences(PREFERENCE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
return sharedPref.getLong("time", 0);
```

Comment: I like this option with Intent. But how to save timer_value when my activity end?

Comment: Does this stuff goes into a class or what? And how to use that class? Check out my orginal post for EDIT, is that how to do it?